# Clicking on any button triggers my UserService.getUsers function while this should not happen

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I wrote a service to where I put my http request for adding and getting a service. Through all of my project I work with popup boxes (md-dialog -> angular material). Now I face 2 problem. The first one is that after I added an user I will retrieve all the users so my user list will show double. The second problem is that when the application loads is show the users list correctly but then when a click on any button that triggers my popup, the user list will double its self.

What I am wondering is that why this is happening and how to solve it.

Here is a visual of my application -> https://gyazo.com/ad135d42731d5cdc7be9d3b85aa57dc8

Part of my app.js code:

```
zazzleApp.factory('UserService', function ($http) {
        var UserService = {};

        UserService.userList = []//this is the array of users that we use in the controller (and in the page)
        //whatever resides in this array will be shown on the page (because the controller is bound to it)

        //get the users from the API
        UserService.getUsers = function () {
        $http.get("api/users") //your API url goes here
            .success(function(dataFromServer){
                console.log('LOGGING DATADROMSERVER ', dataFromServer);

                dataFromServer.forEach(function(user, index, arr) { 
                    UserService.userList.push(user); 
                })


                //here you should update the usersList from the server like this:
                UserService.usersList = dataFromServer;
                return dataFromServer;
            })
            .error(function(errorFromServer){
            //something went wrong, process the error here
                console.log("Error in getting the users from the server");
            })
        };

        UserService.addUser = function (pUser) {
        //here you should do the $http.post and write some code on the .success() event. 
        //Just for an example I used here the .get() method to show you how to process the request, you should replace it
        //note the return $http.post below which takes our promise further to the controller so we can use it there if we want:
            return  $http.post('api/users/invite', {
                    'email': pUser.email,
                    'role_id': pUser.role
                }, {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
                    }
                })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //code to run if all went well:
                console.log("Service: the user has been added", data);
                //add the new user to the list. 
                //actually, you may want to call UserService.getUsers() here to get an updated list of users: all of them will automagically reflect in the page without refresh:
                UserService.usersList.push(pUser);

            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {//we had an error
                console.log("Failed to add user to DB");
            });
        };

        return UserService;
    })

//START CONTROLLER
angular.module('zazzleToolPlannerApp')
    .controller('CalendarCtrl', function ($scope, $mdDialog, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, User, Auth, UserService) {

        $scope.newUser = {};//this is the new user object. You can initialise it however you want
        $scope.newUser.email = "";//initialize the data for the new user
        $scope.newUser.role = "";

        //this is how you bind the list to the data in the service:
        $scope.users = UserService.userList;

        $scope.isAdmin = Auth.isAdmin;
        $scope.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser;

        //ask the service to grab the data from the server. This is bound to the first button in the page
        $scope.getDataFromService = function () {
            UserService.getUsers(); //after this gets called, the data will be shown in the page automatically
        }
        $scope.getDataFromService();

        //ask the service to add a new user with the API (called from the second button):
        $scope.addUserWithService = function () {
            //note that you can process the promise right here (because of the return $http in the service)
            UserService.addUser($scope.newUser)
                .success(function(data){
                    //here you can process the data or format it or do whatever you want with it
                    console.log("Controller: the user has been added");
                    $scope.users = [];// EMPTY THE ARRAY
                    UserService.getUsers();

                })
                .error(function(data){
                    //something went wrong
                    console.log("Controller: the user has been added");
                });         
        }
   });
```

Comment: You should add your service till the controller just bind the list "$scope.users = UserService.userList"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your service change the function to:

```
UserService.getUsers = function () {
  $http.get("api/users")
  .success(function(users) {
    console.log('LOGGING DATADROMSERVER ', users);
    return UserService.usersList = users;
  })
  .error(function(err) {
    console.log("GET usres error: ", err);
  });
};
```

There's no need to run forEach there and add user by user. just assign it to the response from the server.

In your controller:

```
  $scope.addUser = function () {
    UserService.addUser($scope.newUser)
    .success(function(newUser){
      console.log("Controller: user has been added: ", newUser);
    })
    .error(function(err){
      console.log("Controller: Add user error: ", err);
    });         
  }
```

No need to empty the array and get the users again since the service is handling the data for the controller.

Besides that, here's some refactoring to your code to make it more readable and maintainable:

```
angular.module('zazzleToolPlannerApp')
.factory('UserService', UserService)
.controller('CalendarCtrl', CalendarCtrl);

function UserService($http) {
  var service = {
    getUsers: getUsers,
    add: add,
    userList: []
  };

  return service;

  function getUsers() {
    $http.get("api/users").then(success, error);

    function success(users) {
      console.log('LOGGING DATADROMSERVER ', users);
      return service.usersList = users;
    }

    function error(err) {
      console.log("GET usres error: ", err);
    }
  }

  function add(user) {
    var data = {
      email: user.email,
      role_id: user.role
    };

    return  $http.post('api/users/invite', data, { 
        headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" }
      }).then(success, error);

    function success(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Service: the user has been added", data);
      service.usersList.push(user);
    }

    function error(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Failed to add user to DB");
    }
  };

  return service;
}



function CalendarCtrl($scope, $mdDialog, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, User, Auth, UserService) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    getCurrentUser: Auth.getCurrentUser,
    getUsers: UserService.getUsers,
    isAdmin: Auth.isAdmin,
    addUser: addUser,
    users: UserService.userList,
    newUser: {}
  });

  init();

  function init() {
    $scope.getUsers();
    initNewUser();
  }

  function initNewUser() {
    $scope.newUser = { email: "", role: "" };
  }

  function addUser() {
    UserService.addUser($scope.newUser)
    .success(function(newUser){
      console.log("Controller: user has been added: ", newUser);
    })
    .error(function(err){
      console.log("Controller: Add user error: ", err);
    })
    .finally(function() {
      initNewUser();
    });
  }
}
```

Also you'll be better off using controllerAs syntax to avoid scope collisions.

so your controller will be:

```
function CalendarCtrl($mdDialog, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, User, Auth, UserService) {
  var ctrl = this;

  angular.extend(ctrl, {
    getCurrentUser: Auth.getCurrentUser,
    getUsers: UserService.getUsers,
    isAdmin: Auth.isAdmin,
    addUser: addUser,
    users: UserService.userList,
    newUser: {}
  });

  init();

  function init() {
    ctrl.getUsers();
    initNewUser();
  }

  function initNewUser() {
    ctrl.newUser = { email: "", role: "" };
  }

  function addUser() {
    UserService.addUser(ctrl.newUser)
    .success(function(newUser){
      console.log("Controller: user has been added: ", newUser);
    })
    .error(function(err){
      console.log("Controller: Add user error: ", err);
    })
    .finally(function() {
      initNewUser();
    });
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works and if you have questions :)

Comment: hi just wanted to thank you for your solution although I already had fixed the issue I was having. Thanks anyway